# should I use abstract model in this situation?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I'm wondering what is the best way to represent the models, because there are some fields in common and others that change according to the category.

Example: Common fields: (title, author, content, photo, references)

Category and its specific fields:
Biography (birth data, death data, occupation)
Commemorative date (data, description)
Music (artist, album, year, musical style)

The best would be to create a generic model with common fields and others inherit from it (abstract models)?

Create a model for each category, ie repeating the common fields?

Create a single model with the common fields and have a category field that when selected would display the category-specific fields in django-admin? In that case, I suppose it would be done with jquery? Any references? There is nothing the material has on this on the internet.

Note: All user interaction to register is in django-admin.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> - Often, you will just want to use the parent class to hold information that you don’t want to have to type out for each child
>     model. This class isn’t going to ever be used in isolation, so
>     Abstract base classes are what you’re after.
> - If you’re subclassing an existing model (perhaps something from another application entirely) and want each model to have its own
>     database table, Multi-table inheritance is the way to go.

So if you don't want the parent class to have it's own table, `abstract model` is the way to go.